# Node.js v8.11.1 EPROTO error when attempting to POST using https module

Tags: node.js, post, https

I have a system that is running on Node 8.11.1 on AWS.  There is a function that writes logs to another server.  This function takes a request object that it logs.

My problem arises during the actual POST attempt, giving me the following error:

**Error: write EPROTO 139746875082624:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:827:**

I cannot see anything wrong with my code.
**Why is the error occurring, and what can I do to fix it?**

Here is the code inside of the function:

```
const https = require('https');    
try
{
   const postData = "New log finished " + JSON.stringify(request, null, 2);

   const options =
   {
      hostname: LOG_DOMAIN,
      port: LOG_PORT,
      path: '/',
      method: 'POST'
   };

   const req = https.request(options);
   req.on('error', (e) =>
   {
      console.error("ERROR writing logs: " + e);
   });
   req.write(postData);
   req.end();
}
catch (e)
{
   console.log(e);
}
```

LOG_DOMAIN and LOG_PORT are variables passed to the function.

Comment: What is the value of LOG_PORT?

Comment: @AravindVoggu Excellent question.  LOG_DOMAIN and LOG_PORT are variables passed to the function.  I have updated the original post to reflect this.

Comment: Yes they are, I'm looking for the 'value' :) . httpS uses port 443 and http only uses port 80. If LOG_PORT value is 80 and you try to use httpS, you can get an error like this. Can you check and confirm LOG_PORT is set to 443?

Also post the value of LOG_DOMAIN while you are at it, just to be sure.

Comment: @AravindVoggu I am posting to an ELK server which holds the logs, and I am using a port other than 443. I am reticent to post the actual domain for security purposes of my organization.
That said, am I unable to securely post on a port besides 443?  The domain expects another port, but I do not know if the Node module is limited to only that port.

Comment: Ah, that's not a problem. I asked for the URL to check if there's something like example.com:PORT/kjb/fgh/fgh...

I'm assuming you barred all the common errors. Like firewall / routers blocking ports, or the variables set to wrong values or proxy and all.

It's probably SSL version mismatch. Check which versions your logging server supports and wether you are using an unsupported version in Node. If possible, check server logs on your logging server. May be check the c code at ./deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:827: to see if that would hint at something?

Comment: Version mismatch is my best guess for now.

Comment: I will check with our platform team to see if there are any logs around that.
@AravindVoggu I really appreciate your time!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After further research, it appears that Aravind Voggu (see comments) was in the right vein: the error comes from attempts to use HTTPS for a server that only allows HTTP.

The OpenSSL dies when attempting to secure a connection to something that is unsecured.

The only change required to make my code work correctly was to remove the "s" from "https" in the locations used.

```
const http = require("http");
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be encountered if server side ssl certificate gets expired